# Delete rows of pandas df under variance threshold

Tags: python, pandas, variance

My df looks as follows (I got it with pivot_table):

```
ID_column Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4
ID1       0     1     3     0
ID2       4     2     0     0
ID3       3     1     3     5
```

I want to delete all **rows** that fall under a variance threshold x when calculating the variance of the **row**. I couldn't find that anywhere, only solutions for doing this for columns.

Comment: use df.var(axis=1) to calculate the variance of rows instead of columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to do this:

```
threshold = 1 # define variance threshold    
row_vars = df.var(axis=1) # calculate variance over rows.

rows_to_drop = df[row_vars>threshold].index

# drop the rows in place
df.drop(rows_to_drop, axis=0, inplace=True)
```

To summarise:

Calculate the variance in a row-wise fashion, get the indices of rows with a variance exceeding this threshold and then drop them in place.

Comment: If I do this, I get ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed

Comment: Which line does the error refer to? It worked with my example data.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake, I didn't see the inplace=True and assigned df.drop() to a variable.